# Is it still possible to purchase 220 and 10×8 sheet film?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, film, medium-format, large-format

Is it still possible to purchase 220 and 10×8 sheet film?  I am retired.  previously owned three pro. Photography studios looking to get back into work again.  Need help locating materials.

Comment: Are you comfortable buying online ? Also, why the photoshop tag ?

Comment: Where are you located? Also, are there particular types of film you are looking for (e.g. colour negative, reversal, black & white, particular emulsions, etc)?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of places where you can buy film today. That's mostly online now, but depending on where you live that could also be a specialty shop in your city.

To answer your question, 220 and 8x10 are still made, but not for all emulsion types. 
Ilford (BW only) for example still makes 8x10 but 120 only, Fuji and Foma also make 8x10, Kodak is the only one I know of that still makes 220 but only for its colour negative line.

Here are two US based online shops where you can buy film, and filter by size

- [B&H](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/buy/Film/ci/9954/N/4093113318)
- [Freestyle photo](http://www.freestylephoto.biz/)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever new technology comes around, it supposedly kills the older technology that it replaces. The thing is that technologies rarely fully cover the applications of another one.

Sure digital has its benefits and replaced film for most applications. The thing is that this doesn't mean that film is actually dead. People really like to see things dying (apparently) and made a big fuzz about it like the kodachrome becoming unavailable for example.

All that pretentious drama aside, film is not dead, because some applications of film are exclusive to film and digital simply doesn't deliver.

One such application is size. There's no digital medium format camera or any larger digital sensor readily and cheaply available. Well...[admittedly, there is an 8x10 digital sensor](http://aphotoeditor.com/2011/08/23/mitchell-feinbergs-8x10-digital-capture-back/), but its purpose is to replace the expensive polaroids, not the sheet film. This isn't mass market product either, obviously.

[image]

There are fewer film producers, but they still operate. The business condensed down.

I usually use ilford film, which is available in various types and sizes. They do not offer 220, but 120, if that's ok for you. They make no color film as far as I know.
http://www.ilfordphoto.com/products/producttype.asp?n=3&t=Black+%26+White+Films

They make sheet film as large as 20 x 24in, for situations like "*Hey look at this super detailed large print I got from my gazillionpixel camera, isn't that great? Oh, you have a print, too. Can I take a look? Wait, why is it transparent and ...negative?*"

Comment: This doesn't really answer where you can get film. The OP didn't specify what kind either, Kodak still makes 220 for colour for example

Comment: @Blackbird57 The question doesn't ask where one can get film, but if it is still possible to purchase it. My answer does answer that question: yes it is possible, because it is still produced. My answer also covers where to buy it, because the manufacturer provides information on his website (which I linked to) about that "WHERE TO BUY" is pretty clear in that regard.

Comment: Ilford is one manufacturer, they don't make 220 either. Also, *Need help locating materials* isn't asking where to buy ?

Comment: @Blackbird57 What's your problem? I stated in my answer that 220 is not available. Partial answers are valid answers, too. After all your own answer only mentions two online stores for film, which again, is perfectly fine, just the same as mentioning only one manufacturer. If you want to add something to my answer, edit it.

Answer (score -1):

B&H, Adorama, and others may have online sales, but they have regular phone sales as well. Just call them with your film needs. Even if they don't carry the stock, they will have other suggestions.